# Error when I try to import a module

Tags: python

This question may be trivial but I don't really get it. 
I have two python modules.

This is `module1`:

```
import module2

def main():
    print funcion2(2,3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is `module2`:

```
def funcion2(a, b):
    return a + b
```

I get an error (function2 wasn't found).
If write " from module2 import * "  it works fine. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to `import module2` you will need to call `function2` this way: `module2.funcion2(2,3)`.

You usually want to avoid `from <module> import *` so either do as above or `from module2 import function2` and then you can simply call `function2(2, 3)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
import module2

module2.funcion2(2, 3)
```

You import a module and should explicitly specify it while calling a method.

You can also import only this function:

```
from module2 import funcion2

funcion2(2, 3)
```